# AWS node.js migration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am about to inherit on a Node.js project which is a number of node webservers running on a single EC2 instance. Routing is done using nginx instance running on the same EC2 instance, these node servers connect to RDS postgres dbs and elastiCache redis instance. I am to move this so each server has its own instance and the system can autoscale properly.

From what I can tell the webservers are mainly stateless. 
I am thinking of sticking with AWS products, like Elasticbeanstalk or Opsworks, 
I think chef can handle this change but wanted to know what would be best practices for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scenario you described looks very easy to build an Beanstalk Node application and environment.

You have the endpoints for the RDS Postgres database and Redis on Elasticache, so the only thing you need to do is to create the environment and test it.

If this two is your only dependencies, I would start by the AWS panel. There you can create your Beanstalk application, deploy it and test it.

Be careful when deploying the first environment and point your endpoints [rds, elasticache] to a QA environment, this way you avoid compromising production data. ;)